# Screen divided (vitually) into four color parts. with different problems

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia, screen, amd-graphics, firmware

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tg335.jpg)Details
Laptop :- Asus Rog Zephyrus g14
Model  :- GA401IH (2020)
Os     :- dual boot Windows 11 and pop

I installed pop OS a month ago. I was using it as a daily driver. ( no problems).(screen refresh rate set to 60 Hz always )
The dual boot was setup through systemd boot.

So i tried setting up grub, but it didn't work out, grub was booting me into CLI with no boot options. But systemd boot was working.

i used and shutdown my laptop.

Next day i booted into windows and was playing factorio at 60 fps with screen set to 120 Hz.(in Windows the screen was always set to 120 fps)

And suddenly just my screen flickered and was divided into 4 parts ( see pics ).

I called asus and they said it's a hardware problem and laptop must have hit somewhere.
But i know it didn't.

Please help me any way u can.

**
Screen Problem details :-  #after the screen divided it is consistent at EFI, BOOT, windows

#I also reinstalled windows and pop os ( no difference)
The four parts :-

The top part is very usable with no problems so far.

The bottom part is darkened and retains whatever is shown on the screen(especially high contrast screens)

There is vertical line to on the left side.

120 to 60 Hz

The bottom parts starts to flicker and continues to do say with decreasing intensity. **

Comment: Only Ubuntu and *official* flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use the Pop forum. (*One advantage of Ubuntu & flavors are the many support options, you opted for Pop OS so take advantage of it's support options, or SE Unix & Linux*)

Comment: Parts of your system are the same as Ubuntu, but you're not using a Ubuntu kernel, and you're using software Ubuntu treats as *testing grade* (ie. not ready yet for production systems thus not released for general use; available only should you enable -proposed) so you should be asking in a Pop forum where they are fully aware of what software stack you're using, or a site (SE *Unix & Linux*) which doesn't consider your question off-topic